# Call to undefined method mysqli_result::result() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have run this `code` to show all `columns` from `database` table.

```
    public function autorun()
  {
    $mysql_query = "show columns from store_accounts";
    $query = $this->db->simple_query($mysql_query);
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
      $column_name = $row->Field;
      echo $column_name; exit;
    }
  }
```

but it gives me that error.

> Call to undefined method mysqli_result::result()

Comment: simple_query will not return any result, it will check and return TRUE & FALSE only\

Comment: you need to use $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE'); to get result

Comment: @M.Hemant $query = $this->db->query("show columns from store_accounts");
    $mysql_query = $query->result(); and then i write $mysql_query  in foreach but it shows one column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,simple_query will only return true or false according to your query

```
public function autorun() {
        $mysql_query = "show columns from store_accounts";
        $query = $this->db->query($mysql_query);
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $column_name = $row->Field;
            echo $column_name.'<p>';
        }
        die;
    }
```